# Why my site scroll top when end load pages

Tags: pages, server-load

I have problem when i open any page in my site, Then the site still load i need to read article at this time, So when scroll page down. and at this time the site end load.

It scroll me to top of page.

Why, and how to remove it ?

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to help you if you don't show any code or/and an example. Please update your question with more info.

Comment: i don't have any code to show , its only default theme WordPress and don't update it